# Change Ubuntu default routes?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, routing, wifi-configuration

I'm trying to change the route gateway order.

```
$ route -n

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.42.0.1       0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 enp5s0
0.0.0.0         172.16.0.1      0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlp4s0
10.42.0.0       0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 enp5s0
172.16.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 wlp4s0

$ cat /etc/resolv.conf 

# this file is automatically created by NetworkManager
nameserver 10.42.0.1
nameserver 172.16.0.1

Specs:

$ lsb_release -a

No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

I need the wlp4s0 (wireless) route tried first, then the enp5s0 (ethernet) route tried. So it looks like this:

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         172.16.0.1      0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlp4s0
0.0.0.0         10.42.0.1       0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 enp5s0

nameserver 172.16.0.1
nameserver 10.42.0.1
```

How can I achieve this?

edit:

I would like internet traffic to go through the wlp4s0 wireless interface at all times. The enp5s0 interface is the ethernet cable I connected to a raspberry pi. I'm trying to regularly SSH into the pi over ethernet but still access internet over Wi-Fi

Comment: Do you want all the internet traffic to go through the wireless interface and use the ethernet only for certain networks?

Comment: Thanks for your response! I would like internet traffic to go through the wlp4s0 wireless interface at all times. The enp5s0 interface is the ethernet cable I connected to a raspberry pi. I'm trying to regularly SSH into the pi over ethernet but still access internet over Wi-Fi

Comment: So then you should ask that. http://xyproblem.info/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to use the ethernet for local traffic, disable the default gateway on the ethernet interface entirely. It's not necessary for traffic within the subnet (a gateway is used for all the traffic that goes *outside* the subnet).

You can do this temporarily by:

```
$ sudo ip route delete default via 10.42.0.1
```

A more permanent solution depends on how you configured the IP interface. If it's configured with `/etc/network/interfaces`, disable the gateway entry there, for example:

```
auto enp5s0
iface enp5s0 inet static
address 10.42.0.x
netmask 255.255.255.0
# gateway 10.100.0.1
```

If you configured it through the GUI, you should be able to find it in the network configuration dialog.

Comment: Thanks. `ip route delete default via 10.42.0.1` worked, but modifying the interfaces file didn't. I changed the "10.42.0.x" to "10.42.0.4", an available address, but made no other modifications to the lines you suggested. Any idea why it might not have worked?

Comment: The change in `/etc/network/interfaces` only takes effect after a reboot or `systemctl restart network`, `service network restart` or `/etc/init.d/networking restart` (depending on your Ubuntu version). Don't worry, the `ip route delete` fixed it for now and the `/etc/network/interfaces` changes fixes it next time you boot.